# What is the easist way to add a file extension to a link/string C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I have a page that I am embedding a pdf in. I am producing a @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TopLvlJobs.Drawing) as part of the link path. It is a drawing number and in a file I have a corresponding pdf with the same name. Depending on what page they are on this number will change. These do not have a .pdf extension on them. In Php, I believe that you could do something like this:

```
<a href="/this/folder/.'some data string'.'.pdf">get file</a>
```

Is there something similar in C# to use so that I can add the .pdf extension on to whatever is pulled from the database? Or do I have to rename 1000s of records with the actual extension in the data table...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `<a href="/this/folder/@(Model.TopLvlJobs.Drawing).pdf">get file</a>`

Comment: Thank you! Also if you could point me in the direction as to how to get the imbedded pdf to show the whole thing without having to put a hard height on the item that would be great. I tried style width 100%, that works but the height at 100% seems to be ignored. It comes up with a scroll bar and the height is maybe 10% of the pdf size. I want it to be able to shrink if viewed on a tablet or phone, hence the %. Thanks again.

Comment: can you share your current pdf viewer code, so we can help

Comment: Here is the code on the page for the pdf. Like I said it is there but I have to force the height to see the whole pdf and % doesn't work.  <embed src="~/Content/Pdfs/@(Model.TopLvlJobs.Drawing).pdf" style="width:100%; height:700px;" type="application/pdf">